# How initialize tabs when state changes in vue?

Tags: vue.js

Here is sample of my code in vue.

```
<template>
<tabs>
  <tab
    v-for="c in myCount"
    :key="c"
    :name="c"
    :selected="c === 1"
  >
    {{ c }}
  </tab>
</tabs>
<button type="button" @click="showOneTab">Show just one tab</button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'myComponent',
  data: {
    return {
      myCount: 5
    }
  },
  methods: {
    showOneTab() {
      this.myCount = 1
    }
  }
  
}
</script>
```

myCount has default value of 5. after clicking a button it changes to 1. I need to tabs be removed and just the first appears.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct. But it doesn't work, you can try a computed property:

```
v-for="c in count"
```

```
computed: {
   count() {
     return myCount
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data option should be a function that returns  an object `data(){ return { myCount: 5 } }` not a field with object as value :

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data(){
    return {
      myCount: 5
    }
  },
  methods: {
    showOneTab() {
      this.myCount = 1
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app" class="container">


  <div v-for="c in myCount" :key="c">
    {{ c }}
  </div>

  <button type="button" @click="showOneTab">Show just one tab</button>
</div>
```